# Magento 2.3.0 product image cache not created when resizing images

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I have an issue with Magento 2.3.0 not resizing images from view.xml file in custom theme.

My view.xml:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="cycle_images_new_products_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>600</width>
                <height>600</height>
                <frame>0</frame>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

When i run `bin/magento catalog:images:resize` it seems to work reporting no errors but the images from the above view.xml file are not generated. No images are 600x600px. Also in the frontend I am getting a 403 forbidden error when I try to access the image url direct. `http://www.andrewkurtisdirect.local/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/0ee050c3ffc3555709b9bb6062f4d7e9/a/k/ak_sunset_rocks1.jpg`

The folder `0ee050c3ffc3555709b9bb6062f4d7e9` does not exist in my `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` folder.

Does anyone know why this xml file is not being read when resizing images?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have just added `<constrain>true</constrain>` above the `<width>` element. This produces a `This element is not expected` error in the frontend, so the view.xml is being read.

Comment: have you tried running `static-content:deploy`?

Comment: Yes no joy, also running in developer mode.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution but I moved the view.xml above into my widget module view.xml file and the images were created in the folder above. Not a solution but a workaround for now.